# Adding all connected clients of a user to a group

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I need to add all connected clients of a user to a group.
Right now I am aware of this code which is to add current clientid to a group:

```
public void JoinGroup(string groupName)
{
    this.Groups.Add(this.Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
}
```

In my case I have the userid of the user and my requirement is to find all connections of that user so that I can add all those connections to my desired group. Can you help me doing the same?

Answer (score 0):

I will implement it like this:
After successful login the client will reestablish connection with Hub passing it userID.
On hub user will be added to relevant group.
For example assuming you are using ajax to send request for login

```
function login() {

$.connection.hub.stop(); 

var data = {
    UN: $('#tBxUN').val(),
    PW: $('#tBxPW').val(),

};
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/api/Auth/login',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: funcSuccess,
    error: funcFail,
});
```

Get username as response in case of successful login, (or save username in local varialble while sending request for login).

```
 function funcSuccess(response) {
    if (response != "login failed") {
        $.connection.hub.start();
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            // Call server method to add to group. 
            conn.server.addToGroup(response);
    }
};
function funcFail() {
    alert("LogIn Failed")
};};
```

On Hub I will have something like this

```
Public Sub addToGroup(ByVal UserName As String)
    Dim connId = Context.ConnectionId
    Dim UN = UserName
    Dim Grp = "MyGroup"
    If UN = "xxx" Then
        Groups.Add(connId, Grp)
    End If
End Sub
```